# Правильное отображение времени при вводе

Tags: c++, время, консоль

Необходимо, чтобы время при вводе в консоль, отображалось так: `14:50`, а не так:

```
Начало разговора 14
50
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "pch.h"
int main()
{
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    double hh, mm;
    double hh1, mm1;
    cout << "~~~ Стоимость разговора ~~~" << endl;
    cout << "Начало разговора ";
    cin >> hh >> mm;
    cout << "Конец разговора: ";
    cin >> hh1 >> mm1;
    cout << endl;
    double d_hh, d_mm;
    double cost, res, cost_mm;
    d_hh = (hh1 - hh) * 3600;
    d_mm = (mm1 - mm) * 60;
    cout << "Цена за минуту разговора (коп): ";
    cin >> cost_mm;
    cost = (double)cost_mm / 60;
    res = cost * (d_hh + d_mm);
    cout << "Стоимость составила (коп): " << res << endl << endl;
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: часы и мнуты обычно целые числа,  потому хранить беззнаковый целочисленный тип, а не double. Лучше все завернуть в структуру и защищаться от неправильного ввода  времени.... Структура может иметь метод с аргументом обьекта его же типа,  возвращающий  стоимость разговора

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Добавьте `\n` - `"Начало разговора \n"`.
2) Читайте 2 числа + символ `:`:

```
char symbol;
cin >> hh >> symbol >> mm;
```

Теперь можете вводить `14:50` и должно работать.

`P.S.`: отличная ава

Comment: Благодарю! Я новичок в программировании, теперь буду знать о такой хитрости.  ;)